# Jquery rpg game logic and pushing data to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got into jquery a few days ago and I need to build a simple game.

The game starts off with a selection of 4 characters. Once you click a character, the rest are moved to another div called enemies. From there, I select my opponent and the chosen character goes to another div called opponent. Each character has attributes for different attack power, counter attack power, and health points.

My question is: how would I assign values to the 3 attributes/variables/images so that when I click the attack button, it knows which character is in the respected divs (so that it can do the correct math such as deducting specific counter attack power your opponent has, how much hp they have left depending on which character is there, etc)?

I have looked into storing objects into an array, but got no where. The best solution I have thought of by far was to create divs and the 4 images all with their own ids and classes and then push multiple data to the html with jquery, but I'm not sure if this is allowed. For example can you do:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-atkPower="10" data-healthPoints="20" data-counterAtk="30"></div>`
```

Or by using the attr() like so:

```
variable.attr( 'data-atkPower', 30);
variable.attr( 'data-healthPoints', 30);
```

Any other suggestions for approaching this  would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set data attribute value for all. And whenever you want to retrieve  just on their click event create some variable and retrieve its value like

```
   var abc=$(this).data("atkPower");
```

And use it wherever you want.

And one more correction in your code
Dont use comma between data attribute  like

```
<div id="mydiv" data-atkPower="10" data-healthPoints =  "20" data-counterAtk = "30" ></div>
```

Comment: Okay ty so much

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the specific data such as atkPower by doing something else other than a click event? Like by selecting the divs id and doing .data(atkPower)